# Blockchain and in-game currency (off chain)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I need some help to code an in-game currency (off chain) swap. Explaining: I need to swap a token to an in-game currency, like it's done in many games, like PvU (Plant vs Undead) where you can swap PvU (the token) to LE (the in-game currency), how can this be done? Should I use an Oracle or I should fetch the block chain transactions in my back end to add the in-game currency? Any ideas?

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You want an off-chain swap which runs in your backend server?!

Comment: yes, that is it... I realise that I can do it using solidity events, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

**To swap in-game currency (off-chain) tokens to on-chain ERC20 tokens in Solidity, you need to follow these steps:**

- Create an ERC20 token contract for your on-chain token.
- Create a function in your game's backend to handle the off-chain to on-
  chain token swap. This function should verify the user's off-chain token
  balance, update their balance in the game, and then interact with the
  ERC20 token contract to mint the corresponding amount of on-chain tokens
  for the user.
- Create a function in your ERC20 token contract that allows the game's
  backend to mint tokens for the user.

  **Here's an example of how to implement this:**
- Create an ERC20 token contract:

  ```
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

  contract GameToken is ERC20 {
      address private gameBackend;

      constructor(address _gameBackend) ERC20("Game Token", "GT") {
          gameBackend = _gameBackend;
      }

      function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
          require(msg.sender == gameBackend, "Only game backend can mint tokens");
          _mint(to, amount);
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a function in your game's backend to handle the off-chain to on
  chain token swap (this would be implemented in your game's server-side
  code, not in Solidity):

  ```
  async function swapOffchainToOnchainTokens(userAddress, swapAmount) {
   // Verify and update user's off-chain token balance
   // ...

   // Interact with the ERC20 token contract to mint on-chain tokens for 
       the user
      const gameTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(GameTokenABI, 
      GameTokenAddress);
      await gameTokenContract.methods.mint(userAddress, 
      swapAmount).send({ from: gameBackendAddress });
   }
  ```
- The mint function in the GameToken contract allows the game's backend to
  mint tokens for the user:

  ```
   function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
      require(msg.sender == gameBackend, "Only game backend can mint 
      tokens");
      _mint(to, amount);
   }
  ```

By following these steps, you can implement a system that allows users to swap their off-chain in-game currency for on-chain ERC20 tokens in Solidity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).